# Is there a quick way to add to a JSON the elements of another similar JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to use a location-based API for putting markers on a map project. This API returns a JSON containing data about the 50 closest scooters of a GET-provided location.
I want to combine the results of several of these JSONs, into one that would contain all the data of the scooters in a greater area (if possible without duplicates)

I already tried `JSON1.concat(JSON2);` without much success, as you can see in the code below.

```
var latitudes = makeArr(48.810067,48.900169,30);
var longitudes = makeArr(2.248876,2.42397,30);
var allskoots= new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < latitudes.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < longitudes.length; j++) {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", "https://api-prod.ibyke.io/v2/boards?latitude="+latitudes[i]+"&longitude="+longitudes[j]);
        req.responseType = 'json';
        req.send();
        req.onload = function() {
            var allscoots=allscoots.concat(req.response);
        }               
    }
}
```

A single API answer looks like this :

```
{"result":0,
"items":[{"param1":value1_0,
          "param2":value2_0},

         {"param1":value1_1,
          "param2":value2_1}

         ...
        ]
}
```

**So I'd want to be able to get from 2 of these JSONs, for instance:**

```
{"result":0,
"items":[{"param1":value1_0,
          "param2":value2_0},

         {"param1":value1_1,
          "param2":value2_1}
        ]
}
```

**and**

```
{"result":0,
"items":[{"param1":value1_1,
          "param2":value2_1},

         {"param1":value1_2,
          "param2":value2_2}
        ]
}
```

***the following result :***

```
{"result":0,
"items":[{"param1":value1_0,
          "param2":value2_0},

         {"param1":value1_1,
          "param2":value2_1}

         {"param1":value1_2,
          "param2":value2_2}
        ]
}
```

Is there a simple way to do it in Javascript ?

Comment: If the response is a json object, then you can merge two json object into one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rudimentary answer and could be optimized, but is this what you are looking for?

```js
var r1 = {
  "result": 0,
  "items": [{
      "param1": "value1_0",
      "param2": "value2_0"
    },

    {
      "param1": "value1_1",
      "param2": "value2_1"
    }
  ]
}

var r2 = {
  "result": 0,
  "items": [{
      "param1": "value1_1",
      "param2": "value2_1"
    },

    {
      "param1": "value1_2",
      "param2": "value2_2"
    }
  ]
}

var merged = {
  "result": 0,
  "items": r1.items.concat(r2.items.filter(x => !contains(r1.items, x)))
}

// assuming no duplicates in r2.items

/* 
// in case of duplicates
merged.items = r1.items;
for (var i in r2.items) {
  if (!contains(merged.items, r2.items[i]))
    merged.items.push(r2.items[i]);
}
*/

console.log(merged);



function contains(array, elem) {
  for (var i in array) {
    if (isEquivalent(array[i], elem)) return true;
  }
  return false
}

// credit to http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html
function isEquivalent(a, b) {
  var aProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a);
  var bProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b);

  if (aProps.length != bProps.length) {
    return false;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < aProps.length; i++) {
    var propName = aProps[i];
    if (a[propName] !== b[propName]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solve your JSON. Run my script. Hope you get it.

```
var r1 = {
      "result": 0,
      "items": [{
          "param1": "value1_0",
          "param2": "value2_0"
        },

        {
          "param1": "value1_1",
          "param2": "value2_1"
        }
      ]
    }

    var r2 = {
      "result": 0,
      "items": [{
          "param1": "value1_1",
          "param2": "value2_1"
        },

        {
          "param1": "value1_2",
          "param2": "value2_2"
        }
      ]
    }


    var final_arr = {"result": 0,"items": []};


    final_arr.items.push(r1.items);
    final_arr.items.push(r2.items);
    console.log(final_arr);
```